# How to replicate multiple shadows on <tr> across browsers?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I have this table that applies a couple box shadows to the currently selected item to give it a blue glow and a sense of coming up off the page. It turns out that applying a box-shadow to a  isn't allowed in chrome or safari, but it works in firefox. How could I replicate this effect in a way that would work across all/most browsers?

[image: example image]

Comment: apply the background to the cells themselves?

Comment: this makes the borders between the cells glow as well, which breaks the effect